# Tensorflow how to inspect model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, output

I built a Tensorflow RNN model and would like to inspect the models results (e.g. which features/variables are used and how strongly etc.)

I have created the following files:

- checkpoint
- my_time_series_model
- my_time_series_model.index
- my_time_series_model Meta Data
- train.PBTXT

But I have issues to read those files. I found the following code:

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

model_file = "/trained/checkpoint"
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(model_file)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()

for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
    print("tensor_name: ", key)
    print(reader.get_tensor(key))
```

I get the following error:

> checkpoint: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your
>   file is in a different file format and you need to use a different
>   restore operator?

Is checkpoint the wrong file? it has no extension in my folder, it just says Type is Data?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could `tf.train.list_variables(ckpt_file)` be enough for your task?

Comment: I am just wondering if the file "checkpoint" which is created using tf.train.write_graph(input_graph_def, logdir=destination, name=out_file, as_text=True) is even the write file?

Comment: tried model_file = destination + "/checkpoint" and then print(tf.train.list_variables(model_file)), still get the same error message

Comment: Try using `tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)'. You also can get name format from this function, cause checkpoints could be called differently

Comment: Many thanks. I tried that, I used print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_file)), it prints "None"?

Comment: Check path correctness, see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/974

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the tensor of your checkpoints with `inspect_checkpoint` function from the tensorflow python tools.

Example from tensorflow doc:

```
# import the inspect_checkpoint library
from tensorflow.python.tools import inspect_checkpoint as chkp

# print all tensors in checkpoint file
chkp.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file("/tmp/model.ckpt", tensor_name='', all_tensors=True)

# tensor_name:  v1
# [ 1.  1.  1.]
# tensor_name:  v2
# [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#inspect_variables_in_a_checkpoint

Comment: Hi Francois, many thanks for your help. Unfortunately I get the following message: "Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /tmp/model.ckpt", I can also nowhere find the model.ckpt file?